# Xcode 7 run on Mac OSX 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: swift, osx-yosemite, swift2, xcode7, osx-elcapitan

Am I missing something or Xcode 7 should run only on new(beta) OSX 10.11 El Capitan?

I downloaded beta and after some code changes to comply with Swift 2.0 my project compiles and runs fine under OSX 10.10.3. Am I missing something or Apple changed the game somehow?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Edit:

Xcode 7 runs on OS X 10.10.4

### Old:

Yup Xcode 7 beta runs on OS X 10.10

As stated in the release notes below

> About Xcode 7 beta
>
> Supported Configurations
>
> Xcode 7 beta requires a Mac running OS X 10.10.
>
> Xcode 7
>   beta includes SDKs for watchOS 2.0, iOS 9 and OS X version 10.11. To
>   develop apps targeting prior versions of OS X or iOS, see the section
>   “About SDKs and the Simulator” in What's New in Xcode available on
>   developer.apple.com or from the Help > What's New in Xcode command
>   when running Xcode.

Comment: Do you think therefore it's reasonable to develop under the beta with target ios 8?

Comment: I think you can if you need to test on your devices or emulators but pay attention that you can't submit app developed with an XCode beta version to iTunesConnect (and so in TestFlight and AppStore)

Comment: I wouldn't  recommend developing production apps in the beta builds. Especially if you know a release of the app is required before the official launch of Xcode 7.

Comment: So, I can't submit an app built with XCode 6.4 Beta?

Comment: As far as I know, Apple does not allow builds with any beta versions of Xcode.

Comment: Although... iTunes Connect currently states: "TestFlight for iOS 9 Beta Builds. You can now invite your internal testers to test apps that you’ve built for iOS 9 beta."

Comment: If anyone is interested he Xcode 7 GM seed requires 10.10.4

Comment: To use Xcode 7 final version you need to 10.10.4 or later

Comment: Xcode 7 does NOT install with OSX 10.10, only 10.10.4 and above

Comment: That does not prevent me from getting `INFO ITMS-90111: "Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, and iOS 8 SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software."` Yosemite 10.10.5, and troubles uploading via the application loader (testflights remains in reviews, and mail from apple warns me about a non-existent CFBundleExecutable in the Info.plist)

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**
Xcode 7 runs on OS X 10.10.4

**Old:**
Xcode 7 will require OSX 10.11 El Capitan.

Prior to that all beta versions of xcode 7 are running in my iMac-Yosemite. Currently i am using xcode beta6 in 10.10.4. It is stable version and working fine.

Comment: what if running ios 9 ?

Comment: @ThisClark see this link if its working thats fine but requirments are here
https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/