# Can I install XCode 7.3 on OS X 10.10 Yosemite?

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-yosemite, osx-elcapitan, xcode7.3

I'm unable to upgrade my OS X to 10.11, due to reasons.
XCode 7.3 seems to be the first XCode not to be compatible with Yosemite 10.10.

Has anyone succeeded in getting XCode 7.3 to work on Yosemite?
(What's the important update to XCode that *has* to make it uncompatible with Yosemite?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 7 run on Mac OSX 10.10 Yosemite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798329/xcode-7-run-on-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite)

Comment: Thanks. But - It's not a duplicate since XCode 7.3 is the first version that states it requires El Capitan, while this question talks about XCode 7 in general.

Comment: I installed Xcode 7.2.1 on a 10.10 machine. When opening the application it said "You have OS X 10.10. The application requires OS X 10.10.5 or later.". So you'd need an Xcode version prior to 7.2.1 .

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately no, you can not.

You need OS X 10.11 or later (El Capitan), since March 21st.

So you either update from Yosemite to El Capitan or stick with your current Xcode.

Important? I will say not that much... iOS 9.3 and Swift 2.2, if you are fond of... With the rest of the OSs. The rest is pretty much the same, it's not a major update.

Comment: The problem is that if I update tvOS it's not possible to run apps on it unless I have Xcode 7.3. Any workaround for this?

Comment: Yeap... That's right, if you did the tvOS update you should update the XCode hence El Capitan, no, no other way around. Sorry :-S

Comment: And if you upgrade your dev iDevices to 9.3, you can not debug on them too.

Comment: My problem is that I have a 10.10 machine that cannot upgrade to 10.11 and does not have Xcode at all.  I'll keep looking....

Comment: @Growler XCode 7.2 last I checked... Not 100% sure though.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are here because you updated your device (iPhone, Apple TV etc) and can no longer export your apps to this updated device, there is a workaround!

You can actually copy the newest version of iOS XCode SDK from a newer version of XCode into your older version of XCode.

1
Rename your old XCode.app to XCode7.app, and install the latest version of XCode (yes you can have multiple versions)

2
Grab the folder in your new XCode package content folder: 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.3\

And add it in the same place of your XCode 7.3 or 8.2 version
/Applications/Xcode7.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/

Restart XCode and you will be able to keep working!